# Python decoding String with json

Tags: json, python-3.x, instagram

I am trying to decode this string with python by using the JSON module but I keep getting this error I do not know what is the problem I will appreciate any help with this
here is my code 
    `print(json.loads(data))`
i get this error `raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 38284 (char 38283)`

here is the string

```
data = "{"config":{"csrf_token":"C32Czt1OaAEPfa0yfnexUwIfpRisDbEn","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code":"AE","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"ProfilePage":[{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_501391458","show_suggested_profiles":false,"show_follow_dialog":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"AMEM, sem acento pra amar mais. \n\ud83d\udce9 brendamoniiique@gmail.com \n\ud83d\udcf7\ud83c\udfad\nSnap: brendamoniiique \ud83d\udc7b\nTwitter: brenndamonique \nSe inscreva no canal!\nV\u00eddeo novo \u2b07\ufe0f","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":"https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rbQXKj8fgY4","external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DrbQXKj8fgY4\u0026e=ATNF-ClUCsPTnGqme96AMWs934pGkHIP89zemVqEdVXLGs1DCPVyGA0_OkiLhLCwGDnk7nyP","edge_followed_by":{"count":513368},"followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":610},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"Brenda Monique","has_channel":false,"has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":4,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"501391458","is_business_account":true,"is_joined_recently":false,"business_category_name":"Creators \u0026 Celebrities","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"edge_mutual_followed_by":{"count":0,"edges":[]},"profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/c2f9a7480743127046dd6d77bd4d0616/5E341F01/t51.2885-19/s150x150/70377448_2518104848237245_4413369807659859968_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9c2092522304ee52cd557e4ba41b96da/5E31A379/t51.2885-19/s320x320/70377448_2518104848237245_4413369807659859968_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net","requested_by_viewer":false,"username":"brenda","connected_fb_page":null,"edge_felix_video_timeline":{"count":2,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[{"node":{"__typename":"GraphVideo","id":"2101210976602167456","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Mais medo do que dor.\nM\u00e3os de fada @fabipiercerr\n@brazillianinktattoo\nDesculpa por quebrar sua m\u00e3o amigo! @putzronan"}}]},"shortcode":"B0pAEAihhig","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":127},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1564704112,"dimensions":{"height":1333,"width":750},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5bfebfd491f455e858f84367ae184874/5DA294E2/t51.2885-15/e35/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","edge_liked_by":{"count":3834},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":3834},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ABcqdtXOcnmiS3Mo+8V9OP51m+a7dOMVcSaUrnjIrOxtcljEg4bnHpyKKdHvGd/GecfWipsVczVU1MhZt30/z/Wkb5Vqa2cLVmZcdsqMckfyoqOFPkJ7n/PHtRSGynIhxTE+U1LcHnFOhHWmJ6EyM/fgelFOopkXZ//Z","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/14eaf49f6749eb775bd06dd9a6ab20e7/5DA2D353/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.280.720.720a/s640x640/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a5b2166d543ae26bf279f7326187ab72/5DA2B5B3/t51.2885-15/e35/p150x150/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":150,"config_height":266},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5c3b72b09f6f0d137a55d75d13786ec1/5DA2AD39/t51.2885-15/e35/p240x240/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":240,"config_height":426},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/fdf871515a02848f72391ae8535ebba1/5DA32EC3/t51.2885-15/e35/p320x320/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":320,"config_height":568},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/6d622d9e9bb0c8337558df56bdf7ecf7/5DA296D9/t51.2885-15/e35/p480x480/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":480,"config_height":853},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a340f0feacd2c9d33972ae503e9fe8e5/5DA2BF94/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/66085352_866623317056051_5414623747182996505_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":640,"config_height":1137}],"is_video":true,"felix_profile_grid_crop":null,"encoding_status":null,"is_published":true,"product_type":"igtv","title":"Rea\u00e7\u00e3o ao piercing no mamilo.","video_duration":90.166,"video_view_count":55717}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphVideo","id":"1823351818219301394","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Trabalhar com o que a gente ama com pessoas especiais, se torna lazer, amei conhecer voc\u00eas de pertinho, sempre admirei de longe essa marca incr\u00edvel. Obrigada por tudo! \ud83d\udc95"}}]},"shortcode":"BlN2NFxhioS","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":6},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1531580895,"dimensions":{"height":1333,"width":750},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/1f57785fbd076dca649e5102f0192b77/5DA2D10C/t51.2885-15/e15/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","edge_liked_by":{"count":131},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":131},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ABcqsG7t+gjX8l/wphuYv+ecf4gf4VnRx55/HHrUipn7wGScUDJ45UUksqtn2Ax+YoqIR9sYP0/xopDLMUDKFc87v5fT39KdPgfeAU84HfParK2UgI3EEDoRn+XrVhrSNj0565/xoAxYpWU5f5qK05LT05FFAjUppFcgLub/AJ6P/wB9N/jS/apv+ej/APfR/wAadhXOrbjk8UVyMlzKwwXYj3Y/40UWA//Z","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/bd94e68a518e0b0ea7316a49b986bec8/5DA2A283/t51.2885-15/e15/c0.280.720.720a/s640x640/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/25da56b2753e22ecc42d147b07fdc276/5DA3187E/t51.2885-15/e15/p150x150/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","config_width":150,"config_height":266},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/17690357faeffc9e83295cc70ce7e40a/5DA3B774/t51.2885-15/e15/p240x240/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","config_width":240,"config_height":426},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b814c6604fa781e7938c7bf042a659d4/5DA3164E/t51.2885-15/e15/p320x320/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","config_width":320,"config_height":568},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/3eb4aced5cc8e8f56e366a1c0a9b991f/5DA2AF54/t51.2885-15/e15/p480x480/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","config_width":480,"config_height":853},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/721b0507afb4d563d3fddb158eccafce/5DA33021/t51.2885-15/e15/p640x640/36693531_244321656367003_7741952793291784192_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=107","config_width":640,"config_height":1137}],"is_video":true,"felix_profile_grid_crop":null,"encoding_status":null,"is_published":true,"product_type":"igtv","title":"Um pouco do making of pro @mundololita","video_duration":267.383,"video_view_count":9341}}]},"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":2946,"page_info":{"has_next_page":true,"end_cursor":"QVFDNUNoSHpDQndEb0pRUXpOel9WckNxa3lkTEM4MXo3eFRPUm1oc0F6emplejFsekxUU1VZcWYyZmM5MUE1NDdacXpSMllJWC0tN1NwU1RJSkt5eWhyVA=="},"edges":[{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2151922486391153093","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Indo ali de @instatoiss \nJ\u00e1 t\u00f4 vendo essa cal\u00e7a andando sozinha, tudo pra mim kkkkk"}}]},"shortcode":"B3dKhmZhSHF","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":90},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570749172,"dimensions":{"height":1349,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/3ca56d6a02107b9829a481f384325796/5E372923/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","edge_liked_by":{"count":7420},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":7420},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACEqsxpgVKWCjJ4A600GlzUJltEUU/m54K49e4PQ08mo5isL7QMDH3vf0P17AdKbvzVJ3JasPopm6igkcrUyZyEOOuOMdc9qeIX7YP0NVrstGhzwSOM/0rNGzKLBmbaTkgDknPOM9auRy7xnv3rPgO5sHn/9VXxgDjitDJkuaKi3UUCNFH39sVnXwMpEa545z2+n/wBetYdKY1cq0dzqeqsY9rC0TbzjkdCM/wA6unaeqj8Mj+VTmmGtOZmfKiLan90/99UUtFHMw5Uf/9k=","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/82533b55cf2c0e1ca87bdf6496f73ec1/5E23AADE/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s640x640/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/0ef643f0287638e3c2e533b7bb234bcd/5E34D815/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s150x150/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9221f2f4083889a8e77b99ccac4a19bc/5E36C45F/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s240x240/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/0082899f6ec15fac43a9ce521de1d5c2/5E2C94E5/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s320x320/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/34c96b00697e413879fab9fd193fda58/5E2645BF/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s480x480/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/82533b55cf2c0e1ca87bdf6496f73ec1/5E23AADE/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s640x640/70238656_381298339415147_2571910151171428889_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people and people standing"}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2151209103723397535","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Oi, te liguei, deve t\u00e1 ocupadinho..."}}]},"shortcode":"B3aoUhBBQGf","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":142},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570664130,"dimensions":{"height":1349,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/529341a58c35678dd5bb0b55c922e610/5E216D5D/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","edge_liked_by":{"count":10196},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":10196},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACEqxWIlYKuR2xV1IVY9CVBwMdf8+pqlEMOPx/wrSQs2FXpmueTtojSKH3yeZGGZtpThRnOceuBwcYrN85goQBecc4546c/zPep7mObO8jCjuP60RxI8TkkBgAQD7A/z9KaeiuS1qVN7e1FO3Q+j/mKKq3kIbGMN9RWlbOVfPqDx+NZr53ddxU4B6dD/AFrQtypkKknIx71E9fuNImoQJ1aM9cf5Nc+IHXCkYLHH45weK2rmU27I56E7Sfb/ADzTdQieRY5E5UnHuC3Gc+n9amN1oEu5Q2f7X6UUz7E/9/8AnRVWXf8AAi4sjRMfkHToMDJP8607eOOCMM4y5JJ9T7fQVk24/eJ9RV/+I/Wpb5dPLr6lpXJb64WWIqV2kYKkc8+hH+FR2ExaIwyco2QCOo//AFdjUMp5H1H86jnUCPcAA3PPf86cfeQnoN+wH+9+hoqLzX/vH8zRU80u/wCBVkf/2Q==","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/048c2ee17e60ab95080895ddecc21b90/5E368056/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.169.1357.1357a/s640x640/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/c6aa3ffc4536d3567d97189d48355a37/5E325C9D/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.169.1357.1357a/s150x150/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b34da1ac4ba66b1151e1baa1f01317a2/5E32B1D7/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.169.1357.1357a/s240x240/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/edc0beac13959ce8dc870b82c35e2588/5E3E526D/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.169.1357.1357a/s320x320/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/64f75b7c4d0df242617adae8627a0f5b/5E26AF37/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.169.1357.1357a/s480x480/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/048c2ee17e60ab95080895ddecc21b90/5E368056/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.169.1357.1357a/s640x640/70242699_356069325136465_6184163639773416753_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people, outdoor and closeup"}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2150405593951985561","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"\"A t\u00e1, espera sentada\"\nEu:"}}]},"shortcode":"B3Xxn6OhV-Z","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":802},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570568344,"dimensions":{"height":1350,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/371a801c4dd8565983d31dae77a7a46a/5E2E1FB6/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","edge_liked_by":{"count":21130},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":21130},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACEqy1JzxTjkU+FgvJqSQhh1yf8APWpNLaEQXimMpXjpUkjFeR7flUOS5/z0oATaPWik8s+o/MUUCNc2kIByHG0A5B65+oqPyIo5HOPliAOMnn0qaVy7EbgU4wMgfmDineX5ryrnCyAANwRkUrg0VLiaKRBtGxxxtHIx9elWra3Uw7XxulBIz1/D+f41F9lUMqjO5jg4HGB1PTv2q680KPy2Cny47D6f1oGYn2Z/7rf5/Ciul3e/60UwKZjVuvP1o8lP7op4604VBRH5S9sj6E0wxnsx/EA/0qftTDQAzbJ/f/8AHRRTdx9aKQ7H/9k=","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/6dfa5b245a877c09912f39e9910d2efe/5E34C425/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s640x640/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/54cc65174f8394932794d42d8d1f684d/5E2A25EE/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s150x150/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/cec09eb33e9b96a85b603d46d85aaad5/5E324EA4/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s240x240/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/20a770913704443078747a9e9093f74a/5E64EF1E/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s320x320/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/bca82bcd7c5f8d4900b2c34bf6df8fad/5E2B1744/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s480x480/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/6dfa5b245a877c09912f39e9910d2efe/5E34C425/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s640x640/70631980_551728168916322_5285310180508753159_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=106","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people and outdoor"}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2149505334816215859","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"@nickelback te amo!"}}]},"shortcode":"B3Uk7akhxMz","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":67},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570461025,"dimensions":{"height":1349,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/53c49e922b6f22c28764a121f8d190b8/5E30FAD9/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","edge_liked_by":{"count":8399},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":8399},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACEqwiMdaAM8VdkjDRh++Mcf1+nNQI21WQjO7BB7gj0pdLj62H3UBhbnnIquKuSt50Skn50yDnuM8fWiKNfMGO3JHuP5iktdOoPTXp95UwfQ0Vsea/8AeP5Ciq5ZdieeH834FB5t+/8A3tw/E/4VE0mcrjqQfy/xqSSPysbfmDqCCf6VLCiBHeQbiMYz6moukXZtlPt71Mku05Pfpj61POiGFHQbSchsetUnI7cf5/zxVJ3E109DR3p/fFFZdFVzS7sjkh/KvxLsoJVPRQRn9aN2I9nqcn8KbnPJ5qzIAIxgf55rI1Ig37pl9WBqFTtOcZB4I9R/T60p6j6f1opi3JM2/wDzyP8A32aKjoouB//Z","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7872efc8a47865b7bd14838094606f95/5E19F499/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s640x640/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/865947c3c59bba5c53fa86b9ce026bcb/5E2E87A9/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s150x150/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5a6004950067ba7bbaf15e2b4eb61a55/5E1EA8AF/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s240x240/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/991ce70d66048efe2d80e5daf6eba147/5E2A42D1/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s320x320/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/540e2aaa394797a6368f728cdfe23382/5E341D96/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s480x480/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7872efc8a47865b7bd14838094606f95/5E19F499/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.179.1440.1440a/s640x640/70420951_2405711506371805_6496679180222382909_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=101","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people, people standing and shoes"}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2148823031496514609","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"\ud83c\udfa1"}}]},"shortcode":"B3SJymFhxwx","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":115},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570379688,"dimensions":{"height":1245,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/728146994169a3abf64aa9495ce8c13e/5E650113/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","edge_liked_by":{"count":14124},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":14124},"location":{"id":"129662805","has_public_page":true,"name":"Rock in Rio","slug":"rock-in-rio"},"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACQqftppWreymFa6rnBytlcgqMgE/SiKVXO3kN6H+lWEA5YdGHeqBULMgRt2WH069vwrlVZylbodrw6jG/W2po7KKs7aK3uc/KIygDnge9QMBnIYYHXpVF7ksA2AecEcnp+nNOMhmfaPu9hx1Hf6eormczrUF3/plkeWzjbk8c9cD0xmq2EEykDgN8zdunA+nH50xpRECM5z3z1J7cenc9qeFCkKx79KwvZ8x1ct1yt7Gm04BwBux15oqnsCcL0PNFV7RiVKPUyi4HC8n1/+vTdpZS6nkce5z6f4elR/wfjVqH/VH/fH8jWj0OWOrsZqHBz1rQtZDM4zyVGB9KpzjDVc0v8A1h+lEtrmkdHYuTbw34UVNJ96iuc6j//Z","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7937f2b225ddebbb23725bf46c479048/5E3720D9/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.110.1440.1440a/s640x640/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/c68c881947b03e7f381d95a3993e53a9/5E1CD3EA/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.110.1440.1440a/s150x150/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7956089002e131809afafc0cc263759e/5E208E07/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.110.1440.1440a/s240x240/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b0cfd38b4b392314b6a0798ebba57189/5E2D1014/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.110.1440.1440a/s320x320/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/30bdb0cdc454d3436f5a3b6c760e3846/5E26ED08/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.110.1440.1440a/s480x480/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7937f2b225ddebbb23725bf46c479048/5E3720D9/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.110.1440.1440a/s640x640/71535757_189341858761917_81076465584500668_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=109","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people, sky and outdoor"}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2148203493067266103","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"C\u00eas pensaram que eu n\u00e3o ia rebolar minha bunda hoje?!... \ud83d\udd25"}}]},"shortcode":"B3P87H9hxg3","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":49},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570305833,"dimensions":{"height":1174,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ac9af9e9ccc13e8f3a7dea7f7c428727/5E21F612/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","edge_liked_by":{"count":8066},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":8066},"location":{"id":"129662805","has_public_page":true,"name":"Rock in Rio","slug":"rock-in-rio"},"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACcqtbaYRVopTGXFdFzjcSrtz9aNmKQuDkqQ2egyOw/TJqbac5YHvzx/+upU77dy3Stuun49iMLRUwGeaKu5nykv2mLONwqOS4TBHUdPTrx3+tUiv4ULEGOCSByT9BXHzs7+RMit0EXGMsCcH2xz/jz69KnN3FsAOeDkAflg1D5geQMBwAevfA79s1EGqU2mOVrabf5F1r2MDC5HAwevf39qKol8e34UVfMzOyJsleWz+PzD8xyPxFRtc4II5Oe3I6Y/r3xVt+KypuJfyqFqavTYej7D68EfTIx/WnA1XXqfqKmFNogduophooA//9k=","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/0d5cd5d6f91db7f88634465cad3806d6/5E22490D/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.63.1440.1440a/s640x640/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/636d9dd6d0d2c444f1e4c5240e23bd6a/5E222C9A/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.63.1440.1440a/s150x150/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/c1890a64231dfc28ffcc517fe696ae34/5E2BC02F/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.63.1440.1440a/s240x240/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/1a9d284566fa6e4236f094ed20e8f076/5E1B4497/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.63.1440.1440a/s320x320/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8e8e37178c4ebd012c4d341273a28df9/5E1C05CB/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.63.1440.1440a/s480x480/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/0d5cd5d6f91db7f88634465cad3806d6/5E22490D/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.63.1440.1440a/s640x640/69802783_931862850513383_368990004099701710_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=111","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false,"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people, people standing, shoes, sky and outdoor"}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2148079208868813396","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"\u2764\ufe0f"}}]},"shortcode":"B3PgqjSBxpU","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":81},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1570291018,"dimensions":{"height":980,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/c80bb71715ee9d66d9742ea3398b3d0e/5E29B0E0/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/71512385_1294895257350424_3860920299024042991_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=104","edge_liked_by":{"count":11192},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":11192},"location":null,"gating_info":null,"fact_check_information":null,"media_preview":"ACom13uFiAL556cVKk28BlBIPuB/Wsy+/wBWD6N/iKnsHzEPYkVFyy9vb0/X/wCtTSznpt/M/wCFULu6kiJCDtnOM1Tt7maTndjjngf4UuYfKbJ399uPbOf51JVeN9yZyW9z/wDWqfIpiMy+/wBWw9CD+v8A9emac/7sj0an3nKsPVc/l/8Aqqlp743D6GpK6mjdN8n481nsyAllGMYKj0x1q8ZMA1lN8vI+VvTt7nP9Kh7mi2NmI4jGeOM/nzVqs/zMj6irwFWiGUbrp9VIrM09S77R1Iooo7ie6Nn7Mp4JJ/T/ABqKSwRwMkjnPY/4UUUWC5E6GNip54zxWip4H0oopIZ//9k=","owner":{"id":"501391458","username":"brenda"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f0546a4183139ecfcf0b6d094342af01/5E1F2DD8/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c66.0.1307.1307a/s640x640/71512385_1294895257350424_3860920299024042991_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=104","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/44b63ad614c7a2206df0fdb0c0a2be81/5E38514F/t51.2885-15/e35/c66.0.1307.1307a/s150x150/71512385_1294895257350424_3860920299024042991_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=104","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/28ec1778b5d5a5764b640fdff171220c/5E369449/t51.2885-15/e35/c66.0.1307.1307a/s240x240/71512385_1294895257350424_3860920299024042991_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fauh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=104"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not a valid JSON, it is missing many closing brackets. You can use a JSON validator online such as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com that will show you all the errors.

To be more specific add `]}}]}}}}]}}` at the end of your string and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com, actually the was a semicolon in the string which was causing the whole issue, I was able to figure it out with the help of https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com